# PHP replace string after using file_get_contents

Tags: php, preg-replace, file-get-contents, str-replace

Hi I am looking to replace words in an html email I am loading via **file_get_contents**

Here is my code:

```
<?

$message = file_get_contents("http://www.MYwebsiteExample.com/EmailConfirmation.php");


$message =  preg_replace('/SAD/', "HAPPY", $message);
// Also tried this below and it does not work either
 $message = str_replace('/SAD/', "HAPPY", $message);

?>
```

I am hoping to find all the patters of SAD (case sensitive) and  replace them with HAPPY. For some reason if I use **file_get_contents** it doesn't seem to be working.

Thanks

**UPDATE: Jan 22, 2013**

Actually, sorry Correction when I add the $ it does not work. Its not necessary for my code. I can do a work around but this does not work below:

```
$message = str_replace("$SAD", "HAPPY", $message); /// does not work. Not sure why
$message = str_replace("SAD", "HAPPY", $message); /// without the $ it does work.
```

Comment: What does "it doesn't seem to be working" mean?  Are you getting errors? Unexpected results?

Comment: what does `var_dump($message);` output? You might not even be getting any results. [allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) might be set to off.

Comment: ok I made an update. It won't work with the $ and not sure why. It's not necessary for my code but just curious as to why not.

Comment: The file you're pulling in is a HTML file, and there might actually be *no literal "SAD"* in it anywhere. There might be, for example, `<span class="firstletter">S</span>AD`. If this is the case, you would need a different regexp, or better still, use DOM manipulation.

Comment: `$SAD` is a variable called `$SAD` (undefined in your code), not the text `"SAD"` -- that's what in your second line.

Comment: Also, you had better use explicit PHP tags - `<?php`, not `<?`. Just to pick up a good habit ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$message = str_replace("$SAD", "HAPPY", $message);
```

needs to be:

```
$message = str_replace('$SAD', "HAPPY", $message);
```

Otherwise PHP will interpret it as the variable `$SAD`. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/difference-between-single-quote-and-double-quote-string-in-php) for an explanation on the difference between single and double quotes.

Comment: Or maybe just `$message = str_replace('SAD', 'HAPPY', $message);`? Not super clear why that dollar sign is in there...

Comment: YOU GOT IT. That worked. I will mark the answer correct when it allows me to. You rock. Thank you so much!

Comment: @lserni I think OP is trying to replace template variables in a file which happen to have the format of a PHP variable. Should be using a template variable like `%{SAD}` for example instead.

Comment: Thank you S&B! I mean @cryptic. S&B =  Smart & Beautiful. :) Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use regular expressions for this; it's simple string replacement:

```
$message = strtr($message, array(
    '$SAD' => 'HAPPY',
));
```

Btw, if you use `"$SAD"` for the search string, PHP will try to evaluate a variable called `$SAD`, which doesn't exist and will throw a notice if your [`error_reporting`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) is configured to show it.

Comment: You're answer worked as well @Jack. Thank you. What is the downfall of using a regular expression as opposed to the string replacement?

Comment: @PapaDeBeau Regular expressions are more powerful but take up more resources and can be slower in execution. Besides that, programming is all about developing a sense of finesse for making something work as simple as possible :)

Comment: @jack I am inclined to use the second part of your statement as a claim for my company. https://renoi.de/en :D

Comment: @Lightningsoul go for it :)