# PHP include HTML and echo out variable

Tags: php, html, string

I am working on a script with templates. So I have this PHP code:

```
<?php
$string = "TEST";
echo(file_get_contents('themes/default/test.html'));
?>
```

And I have this HTML (the `test.html` file):

```
<html>
  <p>{$string}</p>
</html>
```

How can I make PHP actually display the variable inside the curly brackets? At the moment it displays `{$string}`.

P.S: 
The string might also be an object with many many variables, and I will display them like that: `{$object->variable}`.

P.S 2: The HTML must stay as it is. This works:

```
$string = "I'm working!"
echo("The string is {$string}");
```

I need to use the same principle to display the value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP replace string after using file\_get\_contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466090/php-replace-string-after-using-file-get-contents)

Comment: Checkout this Question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065387/how-replace-variable-in-string-with-value-in-php

Comment: e.g. `echo str_replace('{$string}', $string, file_get_contents('themes/default/test.html'));`

Comment: Thank you, guys, for the links. The thing is the string might be retrieved from an object with many many variables, so I need to use it like in my example.

Comment: Another way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17869964/replacing-string-within-php-file

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, use one of the many readily available solutions. (e.g. [twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/), [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/))

Comment: @Yoshi Yep, smarty looks like what I'm looking for. Please post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: long discussion, and got a solution.. from this question read it, i have updated my answer... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17869964/replacing-string-within-php-file ... and dont forget to appreciate this person.. he deserves for it.

Comment: this person deserve for appreciation,  don't forget..

Comment: Nope, it's not what I'm looking for. I still need to modify the HTML.

Comment: What do u mean, still inprogress??

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to achieve the desired result:

```
<?php
$string = "TEST";
$doc = file_get_contents('themes/default/test.html'));
echo preg_replace('/\{([A-Z]+)\}/', "$$1", $doc);
?>
```

P.S. Please note that it will assume that every string wrapped in **{ }** 
has a variable defined. So **No error checking** is implemented in the code above. furthermore it assumes that all variables have only **alpha** characters.

Comment: Perhaps mention that $$1 will replace whatever is found in {} with the contents of the var found

Answer (score 0):

It's simple to use echo.

```
<html>
  <p>{<?php echo $string;?>}</p>
</html>
```

**UPDATE 1:**

After reading so many comments, found a solution, try this:

```
$string = "TEST";

$template = file_get_contents('themes/default/test.html', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);

$page = str_replace('{$string}',$string,$template);

echo $page;
```

Comment: Inside themes/default/test.html there is a {$string} it will of course not be rendered as PHP when it is retrieved using file_get

Comment: I know, but I have to use it like that. I've seen a script before that displayed variables as in my example, but I don't know how to do it. I do not have to use `file_get_contents`, but I have to retrieve the content somehow.

Comment: Yes, it's working, but I still need to know the variables when I'm reading the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

All you PHP must be in a `<?php ?>` block like this:

```
<html>
  <p><?php echo "{" . $string . "}";?></p>
</html>
```

Comment: But it is not in PHP, it is in HTML

Comment: Hi! Yes, that's a simple solution, but I have to only use brackets and variable inside. I've seen a script that displayed the variables like in my example before, so I know it's possible.

Comment: @mplungjan  i don't get it :/.

Comment: @user3284463 He is trying to build a mini-templating engine that will automatically replace values wrapped in *{}* with variables (if they exist)

Comment: The {$string}] is in the html file he gets using file_get

Comment: @SaqibAmin yes, that's what it is.

Comment: ohh, how can u get the php variables in .html file?

Comment: @user3284463 the HTML must stay as it is in my example. I can only update the PHP.

Comment: @devpro I'm displaying the HTML in a PHP file, so I'm sure I can.

Comment: @devpro he is reading the file using `file_get_contents`, so a big string of HTML document which will have those wrapped variables too, he wants to parse them afterwards

Comment: I don't need to use `file_get_contents`. I have to retrieve the HTML somehow (it doesn't matter how) and display the variables.

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible to save your replacees in an array instead of normal variables you could use code below. I'm using it with a similar use case.

```
function loadFile($path) {
    $vars = array();
    $vars['string'] = "value";

    $patterns = array_map("maskPattern", array_keys($vars));
    $result = str_replace($patterns, $vars, file_get_contents($path));

    return $result;
}

function maskPattern($value) {
    return "{$" . $value . "}";
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I might have an object with many many variables, so I will need to display them like that: `{$object->variable}`, so this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the variable to replace in the html you can use the PHP function 'str_replace'. For your script,

```
$string = "TEST";

$content = file_get_contents('test.html');
$content = str_replace('{$string}', $string, $content);

echo($content);
```

Comment: I don't know it. It might be a `$variable` type or retrieved from an object like that: `$object->variable`.