# Setting php variable in html file using file_get_contents()

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I have an automated email system set up to send an html file as an email. I bring that file into my email with PHPMailer, using

```
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('mailContent.html'), dirname(__FILE__));
```

In the PHP source, before I add the mailContent.html, I have a variable `$name='John Appleseed'` (it is dynamic, this is just an example)

In the HTML file, I'm wondering if there is a way that I can use this `$name` variable in a `<p>` tag.

Comment: not with file_get_contents. it just slurps in some bytes and returns those bytes as a string. If you were doing `include()`, then any php inside that html would get executed, but then it also wouldn't return the generated html as a string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466090/php-replace-string-after-using-file-get-contents

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP replace string after using file\_get\_contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466090/php-replace-string-after-using-file-get-contents)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add a special string like `%name%` in your `mailContent.html` file, then you can replace this string with the value your want:

In `mailContent.html`:

```
Hello %name%,
…
```

In your PHP code:

```
$name='John Appleseed';

$content = str_replace('%name%', $name, file_get_contents('mailContent.html'));
```

`$content` will have the value `Hello %name%, …`, you can send it:

```
$mail->msgHTML($content, dirname(__FILE__));
```

---

You can also replace several strings in one call to [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) by using two arrays:

```
$content = str_replace(
    array('%name%', '%foo%'),
    array($name,    $foo),
    file_get_contents('mailContent.html')
);
```

---

And you can also replace several strings in one call to [`strtr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.strtr.php) by using one array:

```
$content = strtr(
    file_get_contents('mailContent.html'),
    array(
        '%name%' => $name,
        '%foo%' => $foo,
    )
);
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you

Comment: not a very scalable solution, but that is a viable solution as well.

Comment: @self I added some code to perform several replacements in the same call to `str_replace()`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a templating system for this.  Templating can be done with PHP itself by writing your HTML in a `.php` file like this:

### template.php:

```
<html>
<body>
    <p>
        Hi <?= $name ?>,
    </p>
    <p>
        This is an email message.  <?= $someVariable ?>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Variables are added using `<?= $variable ?>` or `<?php echo $variable ?>`.  Make sure your variables are properly escaped HTML using `htmlspecialchars()` if they come from user input.

And then to the template in your program, do something like this:

```
$name = 'John Appleseed';
$someVariable = 'Foo Bar';

ob_start();
include('template.php');
$message = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$mail->msgHTML($message, dirname(__FILE__));
```

As well as using PHP for simple templating, you can use templating languages for PHP such as [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/).

Comment: +1 for using a templating language - [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net) is old but still much more flexible than Twig, also faster and uses less memory!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function to do it using [`extract`](http://php.net/extract), and [`ob_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php)

`extract` will turn keys into variables with their value of key in the array. Hope that makes sense. It will turn array keys into variables.

```
function getHTMLWithDynamicVars(array $arr, $file)
{
    ob_start();

    extract($arr);

    include($file);

    $realData = ob_get_contents();

    ob_end_clean();

    return $realData;
}
```

Caller example:

```
$htmlFile = getHTMLWithDynamicVars(['name' => $name], 'mailContent.html');
```

Comment: What should be written in the source HTML file? Will it replace `name`?

Comment: You can do `<h1><?php echo $name; ?></h1>` . Just use the source file as you would a html file with variables in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

In one of my older scripts I have a function which parses a file for variables that look like `{{ variableName }}` and have them replaced from an array lookup.

```
function parseVars($emailFile, $vars) {
    $vSearch = preg_match_all('/{{.*?}}/', $emailFile, $vVariables);

    for ($i=0; $i < $vSearch; $i++) {
        $vVariables[0][$i] = str_replace(array('{{', '}}'), NULL, $vVariables[0][$i]);
    }

    if(count($vVariables[0]) == 0) {
        throw new TemplateException("There are no variables to replace.");
    }

    $formattedFile = '';
    foreach ($vVariables[0] as $value) {
        $formattedFile = str_replace('{{'.$value.'}}', $vars[$value], $formattedFile);
    }

    return $formattedFile;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the `$name` variable in the same file where you send the mail? Then you can just replace it with a placeholder;

Place `__NAME__` in the HTML file where you want the name to show up, then use `str_ireplace('__NAME__', $name, file_get_contents('mailContent.html'))` to replace the placeholder with the `$name` variable.